# names of text files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to build a list from all the names of the text files in the current working directory ...

I wrote something like this but it's not really working i just saw this on the net

`String[] allomanyok2 = fl.list();` where `fl` is a `File` type ....

I need the names of the text files because i have to do different things with them ...

Can anyone help me how can i get this names in a list or something? ... thx anticipated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want text files with `.txt` extension, you can do the following:

```
File file = new File("myDirectory");
String[] myTextFiles = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"); // Andrew Thompson's comment
    }
});
```

Here the `list()` method takes a `FilenameFilter` anonymous class which implements the `accept(File, String)` method. This method simply checks if the file name ends with `.txt`, returns true if it does, returns false if it doesn't.

The `list()` method will then only return the files that end with `.txt`.

If you want your array as a list:

```
List<String> myListTextFiles = Arrays.asList(myTextFiles);
```

Comment: Are you using `java.io.File`?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Sorry, I tried to edit your answer instead of mine

Comment: `list()` can either take no arguments or take a single `FilenameFilter`. You must be doing something else.

Comment: I would recommend `return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("txt");` for catching `README.TXT`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a to use `File#list(FilenameFilter)`. Implement a filter which only accepts strings that end in `txt`. I am assuming all text files will have a `.txt` extension.

```
String[] allomanyok2 = fl.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    };
});
```

Comment: and how should i do that? i'm quite new to Java so there are things that i'm not familiar with ... yet :p

Comment: I would recommend `return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("txt");` for catching `README.TXT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File workingDir = new File(".");
String[] textFiles = workingDir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".txt");
    };
});
```

Comment: I would recommend `return name.toLowerCase().endsWith("txt");` for catching `README.TXT`.